# Finding residues of rational functions with extremely large powers

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$h(z)=\frac{5z^{2015} + 7z^{2010} - 38z^5 + z^4 - 2z^3 + 5}{7z^{2016} + 2z^{2013} - 6z^8 + 3z^7 + z^5 - 4z^2 - z + 111}$

Find the sum of the residues of h at its poles in $C$

How do I find the residues when the powers are very large?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide context? What was the frame in which this problem was encountered?

Comment: We've just covered residue theorem in class and this was given as an exercise.  Right now we're on chapter 7 in Gamelin's Complex Analysis

Comment: Hint: let your contour be a circle around the origin of radius $R$, and let $R$ become very large, so as to enclose all the poles.  What does the integral approach?

Answer (score 0):

Gamelin gives the following exercise

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials that form a strictly proper transfer function and that all poles $p_j$ are simple, then the partial-fraction decomposition of that transfer function is given by
\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{P(z)}{Q(z)} = \sum_j \dfrac{P(p_j)}{Q'(p_j) (s - p_j)}
\end{equation}
From that, the sum of the residues should be apparent